# C# Formulário Flutuante

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, formulário

Boas, estou a fazer um programa onde preciso de um formulário flutuante que acompanha o cursor do rato enquanto ele estiver dentro de um button, até agora tenho isto:

```
private void portaSwitchUpLink_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e, string idPorta)
    {
        DataSet ds = _db.consulta("portaSwitchUpLink", "select s.id from equipamentos_rede.switchs_switchs ss inner join equipamentos_rede.portas_switch ps on ss.final_porta_id = ps.id inner join equipamentos_rede.switchs s on ps.switchs_id=s.id where ss.inicial_porta_id='" + idPorta + "' and ss.eliminado!=true");
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        string idSwitch = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        try
        {
            frmSwitchs = new desenhaSwitchs(_db, idSwitch,idPorta);
            frmSwitchs.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            frmSwitchs.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception){}
    }

    private void portaSwitchUpLink_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (frmSwitchs != null)
            if (frmSwitchs.Visible)
                frmSwitchs.Location = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + 1, Cursor.Position.Y + 1);
    }

    private void portaSwitchUpLink_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (frmSwitchs != null)
            frmSwitchs.Visible = false;
    }
```

Porém, quando ando para o canto inferior direito, o cursor entra dentro do form e entra em conflito, já pensei em alterar a posição do form, mas não ficaria tão bem.
Alguém tem uma ideia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi ao acrescentar 10 pixeis à posição do rato:

```
private void portaSwitchUpLink_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e, string idPorta)
    {
        DataSet ds = _db.consulta("portaSwitchUpLink", "select s.id from equipamentos_rede.switchs_switchs ss inner join equipamentos_rede.portas_switch ps on ss.final_porta_id = ps.id inner join equipamentos_rede.switchs s on ps.switchs_id=s.id where ss.inicial_porta_id='" + idPorta + "' and ss.eliminado!=true");
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        string idSwitch = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        try
        {
            frmSwitchs = new desenhaSwitchs(_db, idSwitch,idPorta);
            frmSwitchs.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            frmSwitchs.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception){}
    }

    private void portaSwitchUpLink_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (frmSwitchs != null)
            if (frmSwitchs.Visible)
                frmSwitchs.Location = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + 1, Cursor.Position.Y + 1);
    }

    private void portaSwitchUpLink_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (frmSwitchs != null)
            frmSwitchs.Visible = false;
    }
```